# How can one create new scopes in python

Tags: python, scope

In many languages (and places) there is a nice practice of creating local scopes by creating a block like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541705/is-iftrue-a-good-idea-in-c).

```
void foo()
{
     ... Do some stuff ...

     if(TRUE)
     {
         char a;
         int b;

         ... Do some more stuff ...
     }

     ... Do even more stuff ...
 }
```

How can I implement this  in python without getting the unexpected indent error and without using some sort of [*if True:*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541705/is-iftrue-a-good-idea-in-c)  tricks

Comment: If you delete the if(TRUE) the above code will still work. The braces {} make a block all by themselves.

Comment: I'd like to point out that `if` doesn't even create scopes in Python, so even if you wanted to use `if True:` it doesn't do anything (beside waste time, effort, and space).

Comment: Classes can be used as namespaces to isolate names inside a module: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57258478/2650622

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python, scoping is of three types : global, local and class. You can create specialized 'scope' dictionaries to pass to exec / eval(). In addition you can use nested scopes
(defining a function within another). I found these to be sufficient in all my code.

As Douglas Leeder said already, the main reason to use it in other languages is variable scoping and that doesn't really happen in Python. In addition, Python is the most readable language I have ever used. It would go against the grain of readability to do something like if-true tricks (Which you say you want to avoid). In that case, I think the best bet is to refactor your code into multiple functions, or use a single scope. I think that the available scopes in Python are sufficient to cover every eventuality, so local scoping shouldn't really be necessary.

Comment: It is exactly for the purpose of readability to create local scopes where temporary variables leave, in order to avoid polluting the surrounding scope. It's a great thing and it's a pity it's not there in Python.

Comment: Downvoted because of this: _I think that the available scopes in Python are sufficient to cover every eventuality, so local scoping shouldn't really be necessary._ Why would they be less needed in Python than in other languages like C, C#, Java, Rust etc? (which all have the ability to create local scopes) I think this answer is bad, since it doesn't take enough scenarios into account. Long methods especially comes to mind. As @Konstantin points out, sometimes you _want_ to be able to avoid polluting the outer scope, and Python doesn't give us this ability.

Comment: So is the only way to create a new scope to define a new function or class?

Comment: Indeed, in world were readability is key, it's strange that the is no variable scoping. There are just so many underscores we could use.

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to create temp variables and let them be garbage collected right after using them, you can use

```
del varname
```

when you don't want them anymore.

If its just for aesthetics, you could use comments or extra newlines, no extra indentation, though.

Answer (score 6):

Why do you want to create new scopes in python anyway?

The normal reason for doing it in other languages is variable scoping, but that doesn't happen in python.

```
if True:
    a = 10

print a
```

Comment: Variable Scoping in other languages really means memory management.  Something you don't need with a garbage collector.

Comment: Last I checked, CPython's garbage collector doesn't DECREF until the function returns.

Comment: Not only memory management. Also avoid cluttering the surrounding scope with temporary variables.

Comment: "Why do you want to create new scopes in python anyway?" You really have no idea? To PURPOSELY limit the existence of variable to a) enhance safe reuse of variables and b) avoid programming errors.

Comment: @RegisMay Have you tried to do any of those in python? As I put in the answer, python scopes don't restrict the existence of variables.

Comment: @DouglasLeeder I know: That's a feature missing in Python.

Answer (score 6):

Python has exactly two scopes, local and global.  Variables that are used in a function are in local scope no matter what indentation level they were created at.  Calling a nested function will have the effect that you're looking for.

```
def foo():
  a = 1

  def bar():
    b = 2
    print a, b #will print "1 2"

  bar()
```

Still like everyone else, I have to ask you why you want to create a limited scope inside a function.

Comment: See my answer below for a  better way to do this, as creating a function to immediately call it once, or creating a long set of long functions. to then call them later *in the right order* is error-prone.
What one really wants is a way to make sections of linear, never-reused 'anonymous' code have a private and temporary namespace to keep the 'piping and fittings' safe from accidental connection elsewhere in the same, probably pages long, linear code.

Answer (score 4):

While the leaking scope is indeed a feature that is often useful,
I have created a package to simulate block scoping (with selective leaking of your choice, typically to get the results out) anyway.

```
from scoping import scoping
a = 2
with scoping():
    assert(2 == a)
    a = 3
    b = 4
    scoping.keep('b')
    assert(3 == a)
assert(2 == a)
assert(4 == b)
```

https://pypi.org/project/scoping/

Answer (score 3):

variables in list comprehension (Python 3+) and generators are local:

```
>>> i = 0
>>> [i+1 for i in range(10)]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> i
0
```

but why exactly do you need this?

Answer (score 3):

> A *scope* is a textual region of a
>   Python program where a namespace is
>   directly accessible. “Directly
>   accessible” here means that an
>   unqualified reference to a name
>   attempts to find the name in the
>   namespace...

Please, read [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-name-spaces) and clarify your question.

btw, you don't need `if(TRUE){}` in C, a simple `{}` is sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the other answers, there is no analogous functionality in Python to creating a new scope with a block, but when writing a script or a Jupyter Notebook, I often (ab)use classes to introduce new namespaces for similar effect. For example, in a notebook where you might have a model "Foo", "Bar" etc. and related variables you might want to create a new scope to avoid having to reuse names like

```
model = FooModel()
optimizer = FooOptimizer()
...
model = BarModel()
optimizer = BarOptimizer()
```

or suffix names like

```
model_foo = ...
optimizer_foo = ...

model_bar = ...
optimizer_bar= ...
```

Instead you can introduce new namespaces with

```
class Foo:
    model = ...
    optimizer = ...
    loss = ....

class Bar:
    model = ...
    optimizer = ...
    loss = ...
```

and then access the variables as

```
Foo.model
Bar.optimizer
...
```

I find that using namespaces this way to create new scopes makes code more readable and less error-prone.

Comment: +1 for mentioning jupyter. For not polluting other cells variables I use plain functions and set them with attributes, since there's always only a single instance. Got here trying to find a better way, but alas... Your class way might be useful in some other context though.

Answer (score 2):

I would see this as a clear sign that it's time to create a new function and refactor the code. I can see no reason to create a new scope like that. Any reason in mind?

Comment: Mostly to organise long 'laundry list' type code. Refactoring is often akin to shaving a yak, especially since the likelyhood of actual reuse is very low.

Often it's reasonable to apply [the rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(computer_programming)), which is *after* the long laundry-list code has already been 'reused' by the script it's in being copied and edited in its entirety a few times.

This is very common / expected behavior in 'analyst' code, which is expected to be working immediately, and is along the lines of a 'quick scout'.

Answer (score 1):

```
def a():
    def b():
        pass
    b()
```

If I just want some extra indentation or am debugging, I'll use `if True:`

Comment: @SilentGhost it doesn't create a scope but it does visually set apart a block of code, which is why I sometimes use {} in C.

Comment: @joeforker well `{}` *does* create a scope, not just "visually set apart a block". To just visually set it apart in C, an empty line is sufficient.

Comment: This is useful for garbage collection.

Answer (score 1):

Like so, for arbitrary name `t`:

```
### at top of function / script / outer scope (maybe just big jupyter cell)
try: t
except NameError:
    class t
        pass
else:
    raise NameError('please `del t` first')

#### Cut here -- you only need 1x of the above -- example usage below ###

t.tempone = 5 # make new temporary variable that definitely doesn't bother anything else.
# block of calls here...
t.temptwo = 'bar' # another one...
del t.tempone # you can have overlapping scopes this way

# more calls
t.tempthree = t.temptwo; del t.temptwo # done with that now too
print(t.tempthree)
# etc, etc -- any number of variables will fit into t.


### At end of outer scope, to return `t` to being 'unused'
del t
```

All the above could be in a function def, or just anyplace outside defs along a script.

You can add or del new elements to an arbitrary-named class like that at any point. You really only need one of these -- then manage your 'temporary' namespace as you like.

The `del t` statement isn't necessary if this is in a function body, but if you include it, then you can copy/paste chunks of code far apart from each other and have them work how you expect (with different uses of 't' being entirely separate, each use starting with the that `try: t...` block, and ending with `del t`).

This way if `t` had been used as a variable already, you'll find out, and it doesn't clobber t so you can find out what it was.

This is less error prone then using a series of random=named functions just to call them once -- since it avoids having to deal with their names, or remembering to call them after their definition, especially if you have to reorder long code.

This basically does exactly what you want: Make a temporary place to put things you know for sure won't collide with anything else, and which you are responsible for cleaning up inside as you go.

Yes, it's ugly, and probably discouraged -- you will be directed to decompose your work into a set of smaller, more reusable functions.

Comment: For those wondering, the reason you want this, is because often one who's job is 'scientist' or 'analyst' and not 'programmer' or 'engineer' just needs to do a long laundry list of boring, one-time-only things. 

And when that list gets sufficiently long, trying to invent and remember the temp variables gets to be a problem. Having the faculty to safely make and remove/reuse temporary variables without having to keep them all global forever is preferable to otherwise horribly-nested calls.

Comment: May also want to use `l` (That's lower case L) in place of `t`, being that it's closer to the `.` key and you'll likely be typing `l.` fairly often. Instead of 'temporary t' you can think of 'local l'.

Comment: This also works okay in a jupyter notebook cell, where you start the cell with the class definition, and end the cell with the del statement.
You can do `l.a=b=c` statements in python, where the `b` might be something like `df['some new column $e=mc^2$']` and you don't want to have to type that all out the next line down. (`l.a` being much clearer).
 But you still want pandas to make that new column so it displays nicely later in another cell, with the Latex intact in the variable name.

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, the python way to execute code without polluting the enclosing namespace is to put it in a class or function. This presents a slight and usually harmless problem: defining the function puts its name in the enclosing namespace. If this causes harm to you, you can name your function using Python's conventional temporary variable "_":

```
def _():
    polluting_variable = foo()
    ...
_() # Run the code before something overwrites the variable.
```

This can be done recursively as each local definition masks the definition from the enclosing scope.

This sort of thing should only be needed in very specific circumstances. An example where it is useful is when using Databricks' `%run` magic, which executes the contents of another notebook in the current notebook's global scope. Wrapping the child notebook's commands in temporary functions prevents them from polluting the global namespace.